# How to connect Raspberry Pi 3 to the built in speaker of a pc?

Tags: audio, audio-playback

I want to connect a Raspberry Pi 3 to my PC monitor. The monitor provides an HDMI port but lacks of a built in speaker because the desktop computer that is currently connected to the monitor uses its own speaker. My question is this: Is there is a way to connect the Raspberry's headphone jack to the computer's microphone jack and then redirect the audio input of the PC to the speakers in order to listen the Raspberry's audio without the need of other devices such as headphones or external speakers? The computer is a dual boot system with Linux and Windows so I accept suggestions for both operating systems.

Comment: "... connect the Raspberry's headphone jack to the computer's microphone jack..." In general, the signal level output to drive headphones would be much larger than the signal produced by a microphone. Consequently, that connection might not yield acceptable sound quality without an attenuator or "pad" between the headphone jack and the microphone jack. Can you share with us what sort of microphone jack you have on your PC? Some use "USB microphones", others use 1/8" TRS jacks, others may use something else. Your best solution will ultimately depend upon what you've got to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a set up to test this but it looks like...

Step 1. Audio to 3.5mm output:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/audio-config.md

```
amixer cset numid=3 1
```

This will send sound to the headphone jack. Test it works first :)
You can make this permanent with raspy-config (see reference page).

Step 2. Play mic input through speakers (Linux):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/123798/how-to-hear-my-voice-in-speakers-with-a-mic

Install pulse audio

```
pavucontrol
```

Then route mic to speaker:

```
pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1
```

A simple hardware solution might be a microphone splitter, two jacks, one socket for the speakers to plug into ~£4?